# How to programmatically read JavaDoc so that it can be exposed in a web service

Tags: java, web-services, javadoc

I want to be able to expose my JavaDoc over REST so that it can be read from within a browser. Is there a programmatic way to read Javadoc which I can then wrap into a Webservice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Spring Boot project for instance, after you have generated the Javadoc, you can create an api-docs (or whatever name you want to give to your documentation) folder in

> /resources/static

and move the Javadoc source codes in it.

This way you'll end up having

> /resources/static/api-docs/

The Javadoc will be available at

> /api-docs/index.html